# Result with Thevenin method doesn't equal node method

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I'm following the MIT lectures on circuits and electronics. They introduce the Thevanin method for solving linear systems in lecture 3 (https://youtu.be/RsJ1eg7XNVs?t=46m49s).

I can't seem to get same results using the Thevenin method as with the node method in this circuit when calculating the voltage `e` in this circuit:

[image: circuit]

This is my result with the node method:

$$
0 = (e - V) * \dfrac{1}{R_1} + e * \dfrac{1}{R_2} - I
$$
$$
e = V * \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} + I * \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}}
$$
$$
e = V * \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} + I * \dfrac{R_1*R_2}{R_1+R_2}
$$

But when I try to use the Thevenin method, I get a different answer.

First, I convert the part of the circuit with `R2` and `I`:

[image: circuit]

Where:

$$
T_{th} = I * R_2
$$
$$
R_{th} = R_2
$$

Then, after combining the voltage sources, I use voltage divider to find the voltage across `Rth`:

$$
e = (V - I * R_2) * \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}
$$
$$
e = V * \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} - I * \dfrac{(R_2)^2}{R_1 + R_2}
$$

I must have done something wrong here. Why do I get different values for `e`?

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with the answer you got with Thevenin equivalents yet, but your answer using nodal analysis is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how you got to the second to last equation of yours. However, let's assume you have the circuit with a Thevenin equivalent circuit substituted in only for `R2` and `I` (your \$R_{th}\$ and \$V_{th}\$ are correct).

Several ways to solve this new circuit:

**Nodal Analysis**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJUqj3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming current flows "clockwise" (in the direction of the drawn arrow), performing nodal analysis at node e gives:

\begin{gather}
I_{R1} = I_{R2}\\
\frac{V - e}{R_1} = \frac{e - V_{th}}{R_2}\\
R_2 V + R_1 V_{th} = R_1 e + R_2 e\\
e = \frac{R_2 V + R_1 V_{th}}{R_1 + R_2} = \frac{R_2 V + R_1 R_2 I}{R_1 + R_2}
\end{gather}

Which is the same answer as you got without using the Thevenin equivalent.

**Superposition**

See Weezveez's answer. It's the same result.

**Mesh Analysis**

\begin{gather}
V - V_{R1} - V_{R2} - V_{th} = 0\\
V - I_1 R_1 - I_1 R_2 - V_{th} = 0\\
I_1 = \frac{V - V_{th}}{R_1 + R_2}\\
e = V_{th} + V_{R2} = V_{th} + I_1 R_2\\
e = I R_2 + \frac{V - V_{th}}{R_1 + R_2} R_2\\
e = I R_2 + \frac{V - I R_2}{R_1 + R_2} R_2\\
e = \frac{R_2 V + R_1 R_2 I}{R_1 + R_2}
\end{gather}

As you can see, all of these methods give the same answer.

Comment: Ah! Looks like I accidentally moved the ground node when combining the voltage sources. Your diagram makes it perfectly clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I did for the Vth is I used superposition. 
First I disconnected the voltage source, which creates a short in its place, making the voltage V1=VR1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLHLEn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then, I disconnected the current source, which creates an open link in its place. Since no current can flow from the voltage source to complete a full circuit, the voltage on V2 is simply V2=V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqGfFs.png)</sup>

By superposition, Vth=V1+V2= V+ VR1
So e=(V+VR1)*R2

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNXe7V.png)</sup>

By voltage division: \$\frac{R2*(Vth)}{R1+R2}=\frac{R2*(V+I*R1)}{R1+R2}=\frac{R2*V}{R1+R2}+\frac{I*R2*R1}{R1+R2}\$

Comment: Cool, so superposition also yields the same as the node approach. I still want to know where I went wrong with the Thevenin method.